# Pipeline works with "nveglglessink", but not with "ximagesink"

Tags: python, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0, nvidia-jetson, nvidia-deepstream

I am really new to GStreamer and DeepStream. I have a pipeline created based on deepstream-test1. This is the order in which the elements appeared:

> filesrc (an h264) -> h264parse -> nvv4l2decoder -> nvstreammux ->
> nvinfer -> nvvideoconvert -> nvdsosd -> nvegltransform ->
> nveglglessink

This works fine as intended. Heres the code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import GObject, Gst
from common.is_aarch_64 import is_aarch64
from common.bus_call import bus_call

import pyds

PGIE_CLASS_ID_VEHICLE = 0
PGIE_CLASS_ID_BICYCLE = 1
PGIE_CLASS_ID_PERSON = 2
PGIE_CLASS_ID_ROADSIGN = 3


def osd_sink_pad_buffer_probe(pad,info,u_data):
    frame_number=0
    #Intiallizing object counter with 0.
    obj_counter = {
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_VEHICLE:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_PERSON:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_BICYCLE:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_ROADSIGN:0
    }
    num_rects=0

    gst_buffer = info.get_buffer()
    if not gst_buffer:
        print("Unable to get GstBuffer ")
        return

    # Retrieve batch metadata from the gst_buffer
    # Note that pyds.gst_buffer_get_nvds_batch_meta() expects the
    # C address of gst_buffer as input, which is obtained with hash(gst_buffer)
    batch_meta = pyds.gst_buffer_get_nvds_batch_meta(hash(gst_buffer))
    l_frame = batch_meta.frame_meta_list
    while l_frame is not None:
        try:
            # Note that l_frame.data needs a cast to pyds.NvDsFrameMeta
            # The casting is done by pyds.glist_get_nvds_frame_meta()
            # The casting also keeps ownership of the underlying memory
            # in the C code, so the Python garbage collector will leave
            # it alone.
            #frame_meta = pyds.glist_get_nvds_frame_meta(l_frame.data)
            frame_meta = pyds.NvDsFrameMeta.cast(l_frame.data)
        except StopIteration:
            break

        frame_number=frame_meta.frame_num
        num_rects = frame_meta.num_obj_meta
        l_obj=frame_meta.obj_meta_list
        while l_obj is not None:
            try:
                # Casting l_obj.data to pyds.NvDsObjectMeta
                #obj_meta=pyds.glist_get_nvds_object_meta(l_obj.data)
                obj_meta=pyds.NvDsObjectMeta.cast(l_obj.data)
            except StopIteration:
                break
            obj_counter[obj_meta.class_id] += 1
            obj_meta.rect_params.border_color.set(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
            try: 
                l_obj=l_obj.next
            except StopIteration:
                break

        # Acquiring a display meta object. The memory ownership remains in
        # the C code so downstream plugins can still access it. Otherwise
        # the garbage collector will claim it when this probe function exits.
        display_meta=pyds.nvds_acquire_display_meta_from_pool(batch_meta)
        display_meta.num_labels = 1
        py_nvosd_text_params = display_meta.text_params[0]
        # Setting display text to be shown on screen
        # Note that the pyds module allocates a buffer for the string, and the
        # memory will not be claimed by the garbage collector.
        # Reading the display_text field here will return the C address of the
        # allocated string. Use pyds.get_string() to get the string content.
        py_nvosd_text_params.display_text = "Frame Number={} Number of Objects={} Vehicle_count={} Person_count={}".format(frame_number, num_rects, obj_counter[PGIE_CLASS_ID_VEHICLE], obj_counter[PGIE_CLASS_ID_PERSON])

        # Now set the offsets where the string should appear
        py_nvosd_text_params.x_offset = 10
        py_nvosd_text_params.y_offset = 12

        # Font , font-color and font-size
        py_nvosd_text_params.font_params.font_name = "Serif"
        py_nvosd_text_params.font_params.font_size = 10
        # set(red, green, blue, alpha); set to White
        py_nvosd_text_params.font_params.font_color.set(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)

        # Text background color
        py_nvosd_text_params.set_bg_clr = 1
        # set(red, green, blue, alpha); set to Black
        py_nvosd_text_params.text_bg_clr.set(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        # Using pyds.get_string() to get display_text as string
        print(pyds.get_string(py_nvosd_text_params.display_text))
        pyds.nvds_add_display_meta_to_frame(frame_meta, display_meta)
        try:
            l_frame=l_frame.next
        except StopIteration:
            break
            
    return Gst.PadProbeReturn.OK    


def main(args):
    # Check input arguments
    if len(args) != 2:
        sys.stderr.write("usage: %s <media file or uri>\n" % args[0])
        sys.exit(1)

    # Standard GStreamer initialization
    GObject.threads_init()
    Gst.init(None)

    # Create gstreamer elements
    # Create Pipeline element that will form a connection of other elements
    print("Creating Pipeline \n ")
    pipeline = Gst.Pipeline()

    if not pipeline:
        sys.stderr.write(" Unable to create Pipeline \n")

    # Source element for reading from the file
    print("Creating Source \n ")
    source = Gst.ElementFactory.make("filesrc", "file-source")
    if not source:
        sys.stderr.write(" Unable to create Source \n")

    # Since the data format in the input file is elementary h264 stream,
    # we need a h264parser
    print("Creating H264Parser \n")
    h264parser = Gst.ElementFactory.make("h264parse", "h264-parser")
    if not h264parser:
        sys.stderr.write(" Unable to create h264 parser \n")

    # Use nvdec_h264 for hardware accelerated decode on GPU
    print("Creating Decoder \n")
    decoder = Gst.ElementFactory.make("nvv4l2decoder", "nvv4l2-decoder")
    if not decoder:
        sys.stderr.write(" Unable to create Nvv4l2 Decoder \n")

    # Create nvstreammux instance to form batches from one or more sources.
    streammux = Gst.ElementFactory.make("nvstreammux", "Stream-muxer")
    if not streammux:
        sys.stderr.write(" Unable to create NvStreamMux \n")

    # Use nvinfer to run inferencing on decoder's output,
    # behaviour of inferencing is set through config file
    pgie = Gst.ElementFactory.make("nvinfer", "primary-inference")
    if not pgie:
        sys.stderr.write(" Unable to create pgie \n")

    # Use convertor to convert from NV12 to RGBA as required by nvosd
    nvvidconv = Gst.ElementFactory.make("nvvideoconvert", "convertor")
    if not nvvidconv:
        sys.stderr.write(" Unable to create nvvidconv \n")

    # Create OSD to draw on the converted RGBA buffer
    nvosd = Gst.ElementFactory.make("nvdsosd", "onscreendisplay")

    if not nvosd:
        sys.stderr.write(" Unable to create nvosd \n")

    # Finally render the osd output
    if is_aarch64():
        transform = Gst.ElementFactory.make("nvegltransform", "nvegl-transform")

    print("Creating EGLSink \n")
    sink = Gst.ElementFactory.make("nveglglessink", "nvvideo-renderer")
    if not sink:
        sys.stderr.write(" Unable to create egl sink \n")

    print("Playing file %s " %args[1])
    source.set_property('location', args[1])
    streammux.set_property('width', 1920)
    streammux.set_property('height', 1080)
    streammux.set_property('batch-size', 1)
    streammux.set_property('batched-push-timeout', 4000000)
    pgie.set_property('config-file-path', "dstest1_pgie_config.txt")

    print("Adding elements to Pipeline \n")
    pipeline.add(source)
    pipeline.add(h264parser)
    pipeline.add(decoder)
    pipeline.add(streammux)
    pipeline.add(pgie)
    pipeline.add(nvvidconv)
    pipeline.add(nvosd)
    pipeline.add(sink)
    if is_aarch64():
        pipeline.add(transform)

    # we link the elements together
    # file-source -> h264-parser -> nvh264-decoder ->
    # nvinfer -> nvvidconv -> nvosd -> video-renderer
    print("Linking elements in the Pipeline \n")
    source.link(h264parser)
    h264parser.link(decoder)

    sinkpad = streammux.get_request_pad("sink_0")
    if not sinkpad:
        sys.stderr.write(" Unable to get the sink pad of streammux \n")
    srcpad = decoder.get_static_pad("src")
    if not srcpad:
        sys.stderr.write(" Unable to get source pad of decoder \n")
    srcpad.link(sinkpad)
    streammux.link(pgie)
    pgie.link(nvvidconv)
    nvvidconv.link(nvosd)
    if is_aarch64():
        nvosd.link(transform)
        transform.link(sink)
    else:
        nvosd.link(sink)

    # create an event loop and feed gstreamer bus mesages to it
    loop = GObject.MainLoop()
    bus = pipeline.get_bus()
    bus.add_signal_watch()
    bus.connect ("message", bus_call, loop)

    # Lets add probe to get informed of the meta data generated, we add probe to
    # the sink pad of the osd element, since by that time, the buffer would have
    # had got all the metadata.
    osdsinkpad = nvosd.get_static_pad("sink")
    if not osdsinkpad:
        sys.stderr.write(" Unable to get sink pad of nvosd \n")

    osdsinkpad.add_probe(Gst.PadProbeType.BUFFER, osd_sink_pad_buffer_probe, 0)

    # start play back and listen to events
    print("Starting pipeline \n")
    pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
    try:
        loop.run()
    except:
        pass
    # cleanup
    pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

But whenever i try to replace `nvegltransform -> nveglglessink` of the pipeline with `ximagesink` i get an error saying:

> Error: gst-stream-error-quark: Internal data stream error. (1):
> /dvs/git/dirty/git-master_linux/deepstream/sdk/src/gst-plugins/gst-nvinfer/gstnvinfer.cpp(2288):
> gst_nvinfer_output_loop ():
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstNvInfer:primary-inference: streaming
> stopped, reason not-linked (-1)

I needed to remove nveglglessink from the pipeline originally, but as nvegltransform is related to nveglglessink i decided to remove both. And in place of them i used ximagesink.

This is the pipeline i am working on (which gives the error mentioned):

> filesrc (an h264) -> h264parse -> nvv4l2decoder -> nvstreammux ->
> nvinfer -> nvvideoconvert -> nvdsosd -> ximagesink

Heres the code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import GObject, Gst
from common.is_aarch_64 import is_aarch64
from common.bus_call import bus_call

import pyds

PGIE_CLASS_ID_VEHICLE = 0
PGIE_CLASS_ID_BICYCLE = 1
PGIE_CLASS_ID_PERSON = 2
PGIE_CLASS_ID_ROADSIGN = 3


def osd_sink_pad_buffer_probe(pad,info,u_data):
    frame_number=0
    #Intiallizing object counter with 0.
    obj_counter = {
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_VEHICLE:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_PERSON:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_BICYCLE:0,
        PGIE_CLASS_ID_ROADSIGN:0
    }
    num_rects=0

    gst_buffer = info.get_buffer()
    if not gst_buffer:
        print("Unable to get GstBuffer ")
        return

    # Retrieve batch metadata from the gst_buffer
    # Note that pyds.gst_buffer_get_nvds_batch_meta() expects the
    # C address of gst_buffer as input, which is obtained with hash(gst_buffer)
    batch_meta = pyds.gst_buffer_get_nvds_batch_meta(hash(gst_buffer))
    l_frame = batch_meta.frame_meta_list
    while l_frame is not None:
        try:
            # Note that l_frame.data needs a cast to pyds.NvDsFrameMeta
            # The casting is done by pyds.glist_get_nvds_frame_meta()
            # The casting also keeps ownership of the underlying memory
            # in the C code, so the Python garbage collector will leave
            # it alone.
            #frame_meta = pyds.glist_get_nvds_frame_meta(l_frame.data)
            frame_meta = pyds.NvDsFrameMeta.cast(l_frame.data)
        except StopIteration:
            break

        frame_number=frame_meta.frame_num
        num_rects = frame_meta.num_obj_meta
        l_obj=frame_meta.obj_meta_list
        while l_obj is not None:
            try:
                # Casting l_obj.data to pyds.NvDsObjectMeta
                #obj_meta=pyds.glist_get_nvds_object_meta(l_obj.data)
                obj_meta=pyds.NvDsObjectMeta.cast(l_obj.data)
            except StopIteration:
                break
            obj_counter[obj_meta.class_id] += 1
            obj_meta.rect_params.border_color.set(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
            try: 
                l_obj=l_obj.next
            except StopIteration:
                break

        # Acquiring a display meta object. The memory ownership remains in
        # the C code so downstream plugins can still access it. Otherwise
        # the garbage collector will claim it when this probe function exits.
        display_meta=pyds.nvds_acquire_display_meta_from_pool(batch_meta)
        display_meta.num_labels = 1
        py_nvosd_text_params = display_meta.text_params[0]
        # Setting display text to be shown on screen
        # Note that the pyds module allocates a buffer for the string, and the
        # memory will not be claimed by the garbage collector.
        # Reading the display_text field here will return the C address of the
        # allocated string. Use pyds.get_string() to get the string content.
        py_nvosd_text_params.display_text = "Frame Number={} Number of Objects={} Vehicle_count={} Person_count={}".format(frame_number, num_rects, obj_counter[PGIE_CLASS_ID_VEHICLE], obj_counter[PGIE_CLASS_ID_PERSON])

        # Now set the offsets where the string should appear
        py_nvosd_text_params.x_offset = 10
        py_nvosd_text_params.y_offset = 12

        # Font , font-color and font-size
        py_nvosd_text_params.font_params.font_name = "Serif"
        py_nvosd_text_params.font_params.font_size = 10
        # set(red, green, blue, alpha); set to White
        py_nvosd_text_params.font_params.font_color.set(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)

        # Text background color
        py_nvosd_text_params.set_bg_clr = 1
        # set(red, green, blue, alpha); set to Black
        py_nvosd_text_params.text_bg_clr.set(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        # Using pyds.get_string() to get display_text as string
        print(pyds.get_string(py_nvosd_text_params.display_text))
        pyds.nvds_add_display_meta_to_frame(frame_meta, display_meta)
        try:
            l_frame=l_frame.next
        except StopIteration:
            break
            
    return Gst.PadProbeReturn.OK    


def main(args):
    # Check input arguments
    if len(args) != 2:
        sys.stderr.write("usage: %s <media file or uri>\n" % args[0])
        sys.exit(1)

    # Standard GStreamer initialization
    GObject.threads_init()
    Gst.init(None)

    # Create gstreamer elements
    # Create Pipeline element that will form a connection of other elements
    print("Creating Pipeline \n ")
    pipeline = Gst.Pipeline()

    if not pipeline:
        sys.stderr.write(" Unable to create Pipeline \n")

    # Source element for reading from the file
    print("Creating Source \n ")
    source = Gst.ElementFactory.make("filesrc", "file-source")
    if not source:
        sys.stderr.write(" Unable to create Source \n")

    # Since the data format in the input file is elementary h264 stream,
    # we need a h264parser
    print("Creating H264Parser \n")
    h264parser = Gst.ElementFactory.make("h264parse", "h264-parser")
    if not h264parser:
        sys.stderr.write(" Unable to create h264 parser \n")

    # Use nvdec_h264 for hardware accelerated decode on GPU
    print("Creating Decoder \n")
    decoder = Gst.ElementFactory.make("nvv4l2decoder", "nvv4l2-decoder")
    if not decoder:
        sys.stderr.write(" Unable to create Nvv4l2 Decoder \n")

    # Create nvstreammux instance to form batches from one or more sources.
    streammux = Gst.ElementFactory.make("nvstreammux", "Stream-muxer")
    if not streammux:
        sys.stderr.write(" Unable to create NvStreamMux \n")

    # Use nvinfer to run inferencing on decoder's output,
    # behaviour of inferencing is set through config file
    pgie = Gst.ElementFactory.make("nvinfer", "primary-inference")
    if not pgie:
        sys.stderr.write(" Unable to create pgie \n")

    # Use convertor to convert from NV12 to RGBA as required by nvosd
    nvvidconv = Gst.ElementFactory.make("nvvideoconvert", "convertor")
    if not nvvidconv:
        sys.stderr.write(" Unable to create nvvidconv \n")

    # Create OSD to draw on the converted RGBA buffer
    nvosd = Gst.ElementFactory.make("nvdsosd", "onscreendisplay")

    if not nvosd:
        sys.stderr.write(" Unable to create nvosd \n")

    # Finally render the osd output
    # if is_aarch64():
    #     transform = Gst.ElementFactory.make("nvegltransform", "nvegl-transform")

    # print("Creating EGLSink \n")
    # sink = Gst.ElementFactory.make("nveglglessink", "nvvideo-renderer")
    # if not sink:
    #     sys.stderr.write(" Unable to create egl sink \n")

    print("Creating XIMAGESINK \n")
    ximagesink = Gst.ElementFactory.make("ximagesink", "video-sink")
    if not ximagesink:
        sys.stderr.write(" Unable to create ximagesink \n")

    print("Playing file %s " %args[1])
    source.set_property('location', args[1])
    streammux.set_property('width', 1920)
    streammux.set_property('height', 1080)
    streammux.set_property('batch-size', 1)
    streammux.set_property('batched-push-timeout', 4000000)
    pgie.set_property('config-file-path', "dstest1_pgie_config.txt")

    print("Adding elements to Pipeline \n")
    pipeline.add(source)
    pipeline.add(h264parser)
    pipeline.add(decoder)
    pipeline.add(streammux)
    pipeline.add(pgie)
    pipeline.add(nvvidconv)
    pipeline.add(nvosd)
    pipeline.add(ximagesink)
    
    print("Linking elements in the Pipeline \n")
    source.link(h264parser)
    h264parser.link(decoder)

    # Link elements manually as streammux donot have a static sink pad
    decoder_srcpad = decoder.get_static_pad("src")
    if not decoder_srcpad:
        sys.stderr.write(" Unable to get source pad of decoder \n")
    streammux_sinkpad = streammux.get_request_pad("sink_0")
    if not streammux_sinkpad:
        sys.stderr.write(" Unable to get the sink pad of streammux \n")
    decoder_srcpad.link(streammux_sinkpad)

    streammux.link(pgie)
    pgie.link(nvvidconv)
    nvvidconv.link(nvosd)
    nvosd.link(ximagesink)

    # create an event loop and feed gstreamer bus mesages to it
    loop = GObject.MainLoop()
    bus = pipeline.get_bus()
    bus.add_signal_watch()
    bus.connect ("message", bus_call, loop)

    # Lets add probe to get informed of the meta data generated, we add probe to
    # the sink pad of the osd element, since by that time, the buffer would have
    # had got all the metadata.
    osdsinkpad = nvosd.get_static_pad("sink")
    if not osdsinkpad:
        sys.stderr.write(" Unable to get sink pad of nvosd \n")

    osdsinkpad.add_probe(Gst.PadProbeType.BUFFER, osd_sink_pad_buffer_probe, 0)

    # start play back and listen to events
    print("Starting pipeline \n")
    pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
    try:
        loop.run()
    except:
        pass
    # cleanup
    pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Could you help me understand what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

NOTE: I am using NVIDIA JETSON XAVIER, LINUX, DeepStream 6 and GStreamer 1.0

Comment: Activate Gstreamer debug with `export GST_DEBUG=4`. It may help to see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may use nvvideoconvert for copying from NVMM memory into system memory as expected by xvimagesink:

...  nvstreammux -> nvinfer -> nvvideoconvert -> nvdsosd **-> nvvideoconvert -> xvimagesink**

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion, but I tried that already and still it throws the same error.

Comment: Ah okay, you said something about copying from NVMM to SYSTEM MEMORY. Could you explain it to me further? All I did was just add "nvvideoconvert" between nvdsosd and  xvimagesink. Is that what you are referring to? Or is there some procedures to copy data from NVMM to SYSTEM MEMORY?

Comment: There should be no more to do than using nvvidconv or nvvideoconvert and specifying output caps as `video/x-raw,...` for copying from NVMM memory (that is mainly DMA-able contiguous memory) to system memory. Be aware that they use different buffer API, so with DS better use nvvideoconvert. It might aslo be related to L4T, DS and gstreamer versions. When I first replied I got it working with my answer, but unable to get it now, not sure if I had a different environment or if it is because of any update since then.